# Set System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser's content to a static HTML literal?

Tags: html, wpf, webbrowser-control, .net-3.5

I want to set up inline content of a WPF WebBrowser control:

```
<WebBrowser>
    <html>
        <body><b>Inline content.</b></body>
    </html>
</WebBrowser>
```

Or alternatively:

```
Dim wb As New WebBrowser
wb.Content = "<html><body><b>Programmatic content</b></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) or NavigateToStream:

```
wb.NavigateToString("<html><body><b>Programmatic content</b></body></html>");
```

Yeah, they are badly named.

Comment: What did you mean badly named? regarding "NavigateToString" method name? if yes than I agree.