# How to show HTML in Xaml in C#

Tags: c#, html, xaml

I've got a HTML string and I just want to show how it looks like.

How can I show this string so that it looks like an HTML page?

Comment: What is the string?  HTML doesn't translate directly to XAML.

Comment: So I should Convert the html to Xaml?

Comment: Is it Silverlight or Windows application?

Answer (score 3):

Try using
`<Frame Source="page.html" ... />`

or `WebBrowser`

[see MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll have to use `<WebBrowser>` control. you will need to call the `NavigateToString` function. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/06/12/wpf-webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `WebBrowser` control, and the `NavigateToString` method as described here - [Set System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser's content to a static HTML literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598030/set-system-windows-controls-webbrowsers-content-to-a-static-html-literal)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Webbrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a wild guess: If you use the WebBrowser control you could pass the string to the document property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WPF WebBroswer control.

You can then use NavigateToString to set the content of the WebBrowser Control to you HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use as per below:

```
- <PersonalDetails>
  " 
+ <![CDATA[  

        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>Name:<td> 
              <td>JD Varu</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>AGE:<td> 
               <td>26</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
  ]]> 
  " 
 </PersonalDetails>
```